# How to use 2 CSS at the same time when printing with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I need to print a table id which inside is using bootstrap CSS for the table border etc., and make a style tag for customize table for no-border on specific cells.

My question is how do I use 2 CSS files at the same time so my customized CSS works too, because by adding them 2 at the same time doesn't seem to be working in my case.

```
<script>
  function printData(){
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("example2");
   newWin= window.open("", "width=480, height=720");
   newWin.document.write('<html><head>');
   newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />');
    newWin.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="custom.css" type="text/css" />');
    newWin.document.write('</head><body>');
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.document.write('</body></html>');
    newWin.document.close();
      setTimeout(function(){ newWin.print(); newWin.close(); },500);
      return true;
}

$('#pronts').on('click',function(){
printData();
})
</script>
```

I expect my table showing with a no border on specific cells when printing

Comment: Loading two stylesheets like what you're doing should work. If you aren't seeing the result you want, it has to do with your CSS.

Comment: Are you pointing to the CSS in the proper folder? If so, then the problem is in your CSS.

Comment: @MikeCluck yeah it is. for some reason it work when i make new css and put in in css folder and call it inside index head instead using style.

also using media=print works too when first only with style but decided using custom.css to clean up space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to use the

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print-style.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

Notice the `media="print"`?

This is a special tag for css files that controls styling, you don't need to use JavaScript at all.

Comment: Or use the `@media print` at-rule in the CSS files themselves. However, the `media` attribute defaults to "all", so without it, the styles should still be picked up by the browser.

Comment: this save lot of work. decide to make the style into css to clean up space